# exception while Installing WP7.1?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Previously I installed WP7 RTW in my machine. Now, I need to install the latest version for windows phone 7.1 SDK in to my machine. So, when I try to install the windows phone SDK 7.1 I'm getting exception, it says, need to uninstall the "Visual Basic for windows phone developer tool-RTW".

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling "Visual Basic for windows phone developer tool-RTW"?

Comment: @Richard: ya I uninstalled and restarted then I try to install but same problem

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling everything related to the phone tools?

Comment: I'd try asking in the [official forums](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/99.aspx)

Comment: thanks all, I updated to Visual Studios Service Pack 1 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update to Visual Studios Service Pack 1 2010, that helped with my issues.